# Have some integrals been removed from the mathdesign package?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, mathdesign

According to [The Comprehensive LaTeX symbol list](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) as well as the [mathdesign package documentation](http://get-software.net/fonts/mathdesign/mathdesign-doc.pdf), `mathdesign` contains `\ointclockwise`, `\ointctrclockwise`, `\oiint`, etc. But when I try to use them, I get `! Undefined control sequence.` Has the package been changed?

I’m using MikTeX which downloaded and installed `mathdesign`, but when using it, I get the warning

```
`Package mathdesign Warning: No font specified on input line 145.`
```

I can avoid the problem by using the `esint` package instead, but it still puzzles me.

Comment: How are you calling the package?

Comment: Egreg, just \usepackage{mathdesign}.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package `mathdesign` *needs* that a font family is specified. Indeed, called simply as

```
\usepackage{mathdesign}
```

the warning

```
Package mathdesign Warning: No font specified
```

will appear in the log file and no action will be taken by the package other than loading the T1 font encoding.

So one of the supported fonts must be chosen:

```
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
```

Some other options may also be specified.

Note that it's not a package designed for supplying additional symbols.